# Want to "screen-scrape" a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, screen-scraping

I have to use a cumbersome Silverlight application that I don't own and that I have to use as part of my job.   In the past a web application that was painful to use I would just "screen-scrape" by doing direct posts, using a browser object to manipulate, call JS directly, but Silverlight doesn't make that possible as far as I know and the company that owns the application says a programmatic API for the application (WSDL/REST) is "something we are considering in the future".  I'm sure someone has figured out how to do this but I'm not searching with the right key-words.   Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am in the similar situation and saw ppl suggested something like `teststack' or 'white'. But i don't know how to use them yet.
One dumb way I can think of is to save the 'screen shots' as jpg files and use machine learning algorithm to 'read' the information you needed.

Comment: I am looking if `scrapy` can do the job or not.